# Epsilon delta proof with log and sin

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

I've been attempting to prove this limit (again). It must be a proof with epsilon delta definition.

$\frac{\sin(\log(x))}{\log(x)} \rightarrow 1$ when $x \rightarrow 1$

so far I have, given $\epsilon >0 $

$\lvert x-1\rvert < \delta$

$\Big \rvert \dfrac{\sin(\log(x))}{\log(x)} -1 \Big \lvert$ < $\Big \rvert \dfrac{\lvert \log(x)\rvert}{\log(x)} -1 \Big \lvert$ =$ \lvert 0 \rvert$

I've used $\lvert \sin(x) \rvert < \lvert x \rvert, x>0$

But this just seems wrong and i would like some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you allowed to use that $\frac{\sin x}x\to1$ when $x\to0$? Without that it'll probably be difficult

Comment: How would you go, if that was the case?

Comment: And yes, what you have is wrong. You are saying, if $|y|<1$ then $|y-1| \le 0$, so $y=1$. Clearly that's not true (since there are many other possible values for $y$). In fact $|y-1| = 1-y \in [0,2]$

Comment: It depends on the definition of $\sin$ and $\log$ you are working with. Are you allowed to use the fact that they are continuous functions? If so, by composition of two continuous functions is a continuous function, you are just doing $\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sin y}{y},$ which as Milten says, equals $1.$

Comment: The exercise should be done explicitly as an epsilon delta proof.

Comment: But what properties can you use? Continuity of the involved functions, known limits...?

Comment: As in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151/81360), you can use the fact that for $x > 0$,
$$
\cos(x) \leq \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \leq 1
$$

Comment: So far we have only covered inequalities for $\log(x)$, such af $\log(x)\geq \frac{x-1}{x}$ for x larger than 0 and variants of this, but everytime i've tried to utilize this and the upper bound for sin(x), i've failed and gotten $<\frac{1}{\lvert x-1 \rvert}$ when manipulating the function

Comment: All you need to know about $\log x$ here is that for some neighborhood about $x = 1, \log x \ne 0$ except at $x = 1$ and that $\lim_{x\to 1} \log x = 0$. Any inequalities that allow you to show these facts would be sufficient for the needs of this proof.